# What is C# dynamic keyword equivalent in C++ CLI?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

There are two project, one C++ CLI and other is C#.
The C# project has reference to C++ CLI project.

In C# I want to do this :

```
//method signature is somemethod(dynamic data);
somemethod("haaaii");
```

Now the method which is in C++ CLI project must handle this.

How to declare this method in C++ CLI ?
Also how to detect data type in C++ CLI ?

Comment: What versions of C++ and C# are you using exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound C++ CLI which is shipped with `Visual Studio 2012` and C# which is shipped with `Visual Studio 2010`

Comment: So your trying to basically reference a .NET Framework 4.0 assembly in a .NET FRamework 4.5 assembly that prove a problem.  Do you at least target the same version of the .NET Framework?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I have set target to 4.0

Comment: @Ramhound the versions aren't important for me at all, You provide the solution and I'll migrate from my current version to any version you ask me.

Comment: The secret sauce is in what you cannot directly see, the binder that the compiler uses to marry the C# statements to the DLR.  It is very non-trivial.  VB.NET has it, C# v4 has it.  C++/CLI doesn't have it and never will.

Comment: @HansPassant You mean I can't do what asked ?

Comment: @Mahdi: No -- you just have to wire things together yourself, the compiler won't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a method signature which C# sees as `dynamic`:

```
void TestMethod( [System::Runtime::CompilerServices::DynamicAttribute] System::Object^ arg )
{
}
```

But if you just want to accept all types, you can simply use `System::Object^`.  The attribute is misleading, as it implies semantics which you will have a very hard time providing.

To discover the actual data type, use `arg->GetType()`.  You can then use all the power of reflection and/or the DLR for discovering and invoking members at runtime.

Slightly more useful is to use the attribute on a return type, since then C# will infer `dynamic` semantics when the `var` keyword is used.

```
[returnvalue: System::Runtime::CompilerServices::DynamicAttribute]
System::Object^ TestReturn( void )
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: this is very appreciate; you have saved a lot of my time; thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to get dynamic with `System::Dynamic::DynamicObject` type

`void somemethod(ref System::Dynamic::DynamicObject data) { }`

Comment: I have tried it with no success. Seems like the `DynamicObject` need reference to `Linq`

Comment: More likely `System::Dynamic::DynamicObject^`.  No, it shouldn't need LINQ.  But you will need to reference the DLR, contained in the System.Core.DLL assemblies.